# Why is the test set accuracy fluctuating and low after adding model.eval?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

There is a batchnorm layer in the model. Before model.eval is added, the accuracy rate rises steadily to 89%. After adding model.eval, the accuracy and loss of the test set become very volatile, and the highest is only more than 60.
here's the code:
The other version is different from the above just in that model.eval() is not written

```
def train(epoch):
    running_loss = 0.0
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    print("---第 {} 轮训练---".format(epoch + 1))
    for batch_idx, data in enumerate(train_loader, 1):
        model.train()
        inputs, target = data
        inputs, target = inputs.to(device), target.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, target)
        loss.backward()
        predicted = outputs.data.argmax(1)
        total += target.size(0)
        correct = correct + (predicted == target).sum().item()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()
        if batch_idx % 50== 0:
            print("训练次数：{}，训练loss：{}".format(batch_idx,running_loss/50))
            running_loss = 0.0
    print("训练准确率为：{} %".format(100*correct/total))


def test():
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    test_loss = 0.0
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx,data in enumerate(test_loader,1):
            images, labels = data
            images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
            outputs = model(images)
            loss = criterion(outputs,labels)
            predicted = outputs.data.argmax(1)
            test_loss = test_loss + loss.item()
            # print(predicted)
            # print(labels)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
            if batch_idx % 12 == 0:
                print("测试{}次，测试集loss为：{}".format(batch_idx,test_loss/12))
                test_loss = 0.0
    print("test accurancy：{} %".format(100*correct/total))
    return correct / total
```

Comment: It sounds like you've got two different versions of the code and with one version you observe higher accuracy than with the other. Is that correct? If so, could you post the two versions and highlight what is different?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The other version is different from the above just in that model.eval() is not written